# product attribute has empty value but it still show attribute in magento

Tags: magento, attributes, product

> My product has empty attribute value but on list.phtml the product are shown with attribute.
>   In the back-end no attribute value are set for this product.
>   All the products are imported through csv. in the csv attibute value is empty for the this product.

Please, suggest me what can i do .

Comment: After importing product from csv, reindexing is must. It may solve your problem.

Comment: I reindex it properly and also flush cache  but it can't work.

Comment: I also import csv again only for one product but it still show attribute.

Comment: check by save that product manually at backend. Bcaz, i had also suffered by this same issue some times when i import product by csv

Comment: @Ranjeetsingh is it working Now?

Comment: Add your solution as an Answer, and accept it

Answer (score 0):

Added one product manually at back-end. some-times csv occured this problem.